# Reading and storing arbitrary byte length integers from a file

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to speed up a binary file parser I wrote last year by doing the parsing/data accumulation in numpy. numpy's ability to define customized data structures and slurp data from a binary file into them looks like what I need, except some of the fields in these files are unsigned integers of "nonstandard" length (e.g. 6 bytes). Since I am using Python 2.7, I made my own emulated version of int.from_bytes to handle these fields, but if there is any way to read these fields to integers natively in numpy, that would obviously be much faster and preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy doesn't support arbitrary-bytelength integers, and using ctypes bitfields would be more trouble than it's worth.

I'd suggest using vectorised slicing to convert your data to the next-higher standard size integer:

```
buf = "000000111111222222"
a = np.ndarray(len(buf), np.dtype('>i1'), buf)
e = np.zeros(len(buf) / 6, np.dtype('>i8'))
for i in range(3):
    e.view(dtype='>i2')[i + 1::4] = a.view(dtype='>i2')[i::3]
[hex(x) for x in e]
```

Comment: I keep getting ValueErrors when I try to call ndarray.view unless I call it with the same type it was created as. What are the rules for avoiding this?

Comment: @dpitch40 it should usually be OK to use ndarray.view to alias an array; it might be an issue with your version of numpy. You can also use the ndarray constructor with the underlying buffer, using arr.data.