# NumPy: 3-byte, 6-byte types (aka uint24, uint48)

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata

NumPy seems to lack built-in support for 3-byte and 6-byte types, aka `uint24` and `uint48`.
I have a large data set using these types and want to feed it to numpy. What I currently do (for uint24):

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([('head', '<u2'), ('data', '<u2', (3,))])
# I would like to be able to write
#  dt = np.dtype([('head', '<u2'), ('data', '<u3', (2,))])
#  dt = np.dtype([('head', '<u2'), ('data', '<u6')])
a = np.memmap("filename", mode='r', dtype=dt)
# convert 3 x 2byte data to 2 x 3byte
# w1 is LSB, w3 is MSB
w1, w2, w3 = a['data'].swapaxes(0,1)
a2 = np.ndarray((2,a.size), dtype='u4')
# 3 LSB
a2[0] = w2 % 256
a2[0] <<= 16
a2[0] += w1
# 3 MSB
a2[1] = w3
a2[1] <<=8
a2[1] += w2 >> 8
# now a2 contains "uint24" matrix
```

While it works for 100MB input, it looks inefficient (think of 100s GBs of data). Is there a more efficient way? For example, creating a special kind of read-only view which masks part of the data would be useful (kind of "uint64 with two MSBs always zero" type). I only need read-only access to the data.

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe there's a way to do what you're asking (it would require unaligned access, which is highly inefficient on some architectures).  My solution from [Reading and storing arbitrary byte length integers from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508010/reading-and-storing-arbitrary-byte-length-integers-from-a-file/11511453#11511453) might be more efficient at transferring the data to an in-process array:

```
a = np.memmap("filename", mode='r', dtype=np.dtype('>u1'))
e = np.zeros(a.size / 6, np.dtype('>u8'))
for i in range(3):
    e.view(dtype='>u2')[i + 1::4] = a.view(dtype='>u2')[i::3]
```

You can get unaligned access using the `strides` constructor parameter:

```
e = np.ndarray((a.size - 2) // 6, np.dtype('<u8'), buf, strides=(6,))
```

However with this each element will overlap with the next, so to actually use it you'd have to mask out the high bytes on access.

Comment: While your method looks nicer, it still incurs reading the whole input several times and storing a modified copy in the memory. Both your and my original solution won't work for 100GB input.

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer for this over at:  [How do I create a Numpy dtype that includes 24 bit integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080279/how-do-i-create-a-numpy-dtype-that-includes-24-bit-integers/34128171#34128171)

It's a bit ugly, but does exactly what you want: Allows you to index your ndarray like it's got a dtype of `<u3` so you can `memmap()` big data from disk.
You still need to manually apply a bitmask to clear out the fourth overlapping byte, but that can be applied to the sliced (multidimensional) array after access.

The trick is to abuse the 'stride' part of an ndarray, so that indexing works. In order to make it work without it complaining about limits, there's [a special trick](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#example-fake-dimensions-with-strides).

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below you can read integers of any size coded as big or little endian:

```py
def readBigEndian(filename, bytesize):
    with (open(filename,"rb")) as f:
        bytestring = f.read(bytesize)
        while len(bytestring)==bytesize:
            value = 0
            for byte in map(ord, bytestring):
                print(byte)
                value = (value << 8) | byte
            yield(value)
            bytestring = f.read(bytesize)

def readLittleEndian(filename, bytesize):
    with (open(filename,"rb")) as f:
        bytestring = f.read(bytesize)
        while len(bytestring)==bytesize:
            value = 0
            shift = 0
            for byte in map(ord, bytestring):
                print(byte)
                value |= byte << shift
                shift += 8
            yield(value)
            bytestring = f.read(bytesize)

for i in readLittleEndian("readint.py",3):
    print(i)
```