# How do I create a Numpy dtype that includes 24 bit integers?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary file that has a record structure of 400 24 bit signed big endian integers followed by a 16 bit big endian signed short. What I want to do is this:

```
from numpy import dtype , fromfile
record_dtype = dtype([('samples','>i3',(400,)),('marker','>i2')])
data = fromfile('binary_file.dat',dtype=record_dtype)
```

Unfortunately what I get is:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

In response to the '>i3'. How can I define a dtype to read in 24 bit binary numbers?

Comment: Its not possible as such, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967339/numpy-3-byte-6-byte-types-aka-uint24-uint48

Comment: I think 3 byte integers are a hard thing to come by.  You'll probably need to read the bytes as bytes, zip in a 0 byte every 3rd number and then use 4 byte ints internally ... (guessing)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508010/reading-and-storing-arbitrary-byte-length-integers-from-a-file/11511453#11511453

Comment: The links provided by Sebastian and ecatmur are probably close enough to this question that this question might as well be closed as a duplicate.  (I would vote as such if I had the rep.)

Answer (score 15):

I had about a terabyte file which was in 24bit four channel PCM.

I certainly didn't want to touch any other than what part I wanted at a time, so what I did was like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

rawdatamap = np.memmap('4ch24bit800GBdatafile.pcm', dtype=np.dtype('u1'),mode='r')

# in case of a truncated frame at the end
usablebytes = rawdatamap.shape[0]-rawdatamap.shape[0]%12

frames = int(usablebytes/12)
rawbytes = rawdatamap[:usablebytes]

realdata = as_strided(rawbytes.view(np.int32), strides=(12,3,), shape=(frames,4))

someusefulpart = realdata[hugeoffset:hugeoffset+smallerthanram]&0x00ffffff
```

This did a copy from the file which was `smallerthanram` bytes of memory long.

Note the bytemask! You need it to chop off the most significant byte of the 32 bit word - which will be junk belonging to the previous sample.

You could also apply it to a single datum like this:

```
scaled_ch2_datum_at_framenum = scalefactor*(realdata[framenum,1]&0x00ffffff)-shiftoffset
```

It's a bit messy, but as good as it gets for now.

You will actually probably need 64bit system to do this.

NB. This is for little endian data. To handle big endian, you'd use a big-endian dtype in the view, and replace `...&0x00ffffff` with `...&ffffff00>>8`

Comment: Sorry: byte mask clips off part of the *next* sample, not the previous. Because it's little endian, and the most significant byte is the fourth one along that we don't want.

Comment: There are other interesting ways to (ab?)use stride [in this lecture on advanced numpy](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/)